# Node.js: "process run out of memory"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following code which leads to the error: **FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory**

It doesn't make any difference whether I set `--max_old_space_size=4096` (or bigger numbers) or not. I have 16 GB RAM on my PC.

System: win10/node.js 6.9.2/mongodb 3.4

I have over 16 000 000 messages in the "chatModel". With a smaller amount of messages the code works.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve the problem/optimize the code?

```
function sortOutMessages(){

var atSymbol = "@";
var rgx = new RegExp("^\\" +atSymbol);


chatModel.find({messageContent: rgx}, function (err, doc){

    var docs = doc;
    var docsLength = docs.length;

    for (var i =0; i<docsLength;i++) {
        var directedMessagesObj = new directedMessagesModel
        ({
            timeStamp: docs[i].timeStamp,
            channelName: docs[i].channelName,
            userName: docs[i].userName,
            userID: docs[i].userID,
            messageContent: docs[i].messageContent,
            messageLength: docs[i].messageLength,
            subscriber: docs[i].subscriber,
            turbo: docs[i].turbo,
            moderator: docs[i].moderator
        });

        directedMessagesObj.save({upsert:true}, function (err) {
            var fs = require('fs');
            if (err) {
                    fs.appendFile("undefinedLog.txt", "error at " + new Date().toLocaleString() + " directedMessagesObj.save " + "\r\n")
                    loggerWinston.warn("error at " + new Date().toLocaleString() + " directedMessagesObj.save " + "\r\n");
                    return console.log(err);
            }

        });
    }

});



}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `limit()/skip()` to process only a defined number of messages at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `docs.length` amount of new `Promise` with this code. What you should be doing instead is to limit the amount of `Promise` that can be running.

Since what you have been trying to write is a synchronous code, I would advise calling the next dbSave in the callback of the previous one.

If you are after a parallel system, I would create a simple semaphore system.

Answer (score 0):

I advise

```
 module.exports.asyncEach = function(iterableList, callback, done) {
  var i = -1,
    length = iterableList.length;

function loop() {
    i++;
    if (i === length) {
        done();
        return;
    }
    callback(iterableList[i], loop);
}
loop();
   };
```

then you call asyncEach  with async save model is very beter

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers! I decided to go a different way and it works for now:

```
var cursor = chatModel.find({messageContent: rgx}).cursor();

cursor.on('data',function (doc) {
    var directedMessagesObj = new directedMessagesModel
            ({
                timeStamp: doc.timeStamp,
                channelName: doc.channelName,
                userName: doc.userName,
                userID: doc.userID,
                messageContent: doc.messageContent,
                messageLength: doc.messageLength,
                subscriber: doc.subscriber,
                turbo: doc.turbo,
                moderator: doc.moderator
            });

    directedMessagesObj.save({upsert:true},function (err) {
        var fs = require('fs');
                    if (err) {
                            fs.appendFile("undefinedLog.txt", "error at " + new Date().toLocaleString() + " directedMessagesObj.save " + "\r\n");
                            loggerWinston.warn("error at " + new Date().toLocaleString() + " directedMessagesObj.save " + "\r\n");
                            return console.log(err);
                    }
    });
});
```